# Azure Service Bus Premium per namespace pricing

Tags: azureservicebus

I am going through the following Azure Service Bus pricing:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/service-bus/#pricing

The pricing page shows

[image]

Is that price for the entire Service Bus Instance or is it per each "premium namespace"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Service Bus Premium is charged per namespace (N), per messaging unit (MU), per hour (H). Your cost will be calculated as N x MU x H. If you have a single premium namespace with a single MU you'll be paying $0.93 USD. For a month that has ~730 hours, you'll be paying ~$677 USD. If you need to add more capacity to the namespace (scale), multiply that bill by the number of MUs.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [`pricing calculator`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/calculator/), you are charged for the messaging units configured in Premium tier. For example, if you have configured 1 messaging unit you will be charged $0.93 / hour for that messaging unit.

[image]